# access to File on Server

Tags: vb.net, lucene.net

My web-appliction references to a file that's in the same maindirectory.

```
Dim index_root As String = "luceneindex"
```

but when use declare a directory with the file

```
Dim directory As Lucene.Net.Store.Directory = FSDirectory.GetDirectory(index_root, False)
```

i get an error.
i tried "\luceneindex", "\luceneindex", "\maindirectory\luceneindex", "\127.0.0.1\maindirectory\luceneindex" ,...

How do I use a file in the same directoy?
I talked to the admin, he told me the setting are correct.

greetz,
tyzak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Java: You'll need to use `System.getProperty("user.dir")`. This should give you a reference to the project folder.

For ASP.NET: You'll need to use `Server.MapPath("~/" + folderAndFile)`. The tilde expands to the physical path of the application.

Comment: i never heard sometinh about System.getPrperty,
how does this work with asp.net?

Comment: Sorry, I saw Lucene and immediately thought Java. I've added the the ASP.NET code.